# What is the use of limitmods flag and listmods in jdk9/java-9?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

As Java-9 come with the concept of modularity. They have added two new flags in JDK.
`-listmods` and `-limitmods`.

What is the use of those flag and how to use? Can anyone explain in more detail?

Comment: Googling `Java "-listmods"` is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

First, these were re-named to : **--limit-modules** and **--list-modules**.

The documentation seems pretty descriptive for them IMO:

> --**list-modules** displays the names and version strings of the observable modules, and then exits, in the same manner as java
>   -version.
>
> --**list-modules** (,)* displays the full module descriptors of the named modules, if observable, and then exits.

While limit-module will limit the modules that are observable.

> It is sometimes useful to limit the observable modules for, e.g.,
>   debugging, or to reduce the number of modules resolved when the main
>   module is the unnamed module defined by the application class loader
>   for the class path

There are some good tutorials explaining in a bit more details (but with the old syntax) what the first actually does, like [this](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/01/java9-jigsaw-missing-piece/) one.

I have to admit that I am still trying to fully grasp these features, so this is more of a reference of where to start digging then an actual answer probably.